# Multilevel data-frame with all same row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a multilevel data-frame df1:

```
FE             F1        F2
C_Step                     
UNKNOWN  0.360360  0.155039
fair     0.135135  0.348837
good     0.180180  0.310078
poor     0.324324  0.186047
```

I want to fill all dataframe with row for UNKNOWN index. In resulting dataframe all rows are same.

desired dataframe df1:

```
FE             F1        F2
C_Step                     
UNKNOWN  0.360360  0.155039
fair     0.360360  0.155039
good     0.360360  0.155039
poor     0.360360  0.155039
```

Comment: provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's **not** a multi-level dataframe. Your dataframe just has names for its `index` and `columns` attributes.

You can just assign using a list or NumPy array, using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to select the first row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'F1': [0.36036, 0.36036, 0.36036, 0.36036],
                   'F2': [0.155039, 0.155039, 0.155039, 0.155039]},
                  index=pd.Index(['UNKNOWN', 'fair', 'good', 'poor'], name='C_step'),
                  columns=pd.Index(['F1', 'F2'], name='FE'))
print(df)
# FE             F1        F2
# C_Step                     
# UNKNOWN  0.360360  0.155039
# fair     0.135135  0.348837
# good     0.180180  0.310078
# poor     0.324324  0.186047

df[['F1', 'F2']] = df.iloc[0].values

print(df)
# FE            F1        F2
# C_Step                    
# UNKNOWN  0.36036  0.155039
# fair     0.36036  0.155039
# good     0.36036  0.155039
# poor     0.36036  0.155039
```